# Java factory but objects have slightly differrent attributes

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract-class, factory

I want to program a factory that creates two types of People which are "Employee" and "Entrepreneur". They both share the same basic "Person" attributes but they also implements their unique ones.
The problem is that if i want to return a method or an attribute that is not declared in the "Person" abstract class the program doesn't find it (since obviously I'm generating an object that is type "Person" and not specifically "Employee" or "Entrepreneur" ).
How do i tackle this problem?

This is the Demo class

```
public class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PersonFactory pf = new PersonFactory();
        Person p1 = pf.getPerson("Employee");
        p1.presentation();

        System.out.println(p1.getComplanyName());

    }
}
```

This is the abstract class

```
public abstract class Person{

    String name;
    String surname;

    abstract void presentation();

}
```

Those are the two concrete classes that extend Person

```
public class Entre extends Person{

    int licenseNumber;

    @Override
    public void presentation(){
        System.out.println("hi i'm an Entrepreneur");
    }

    public int licenseNumber(){
        return licenseNumber;
    }
}



public class Empl extends Person{

    String companyName;

    @Override
    public void presentation(){
        System.out.println("hi i'm an employee");
    }

    public String getCompanyName(){
        return companyName;
    }
}
```

Finally the Factory

```
public class PersonFactory{

    public Person getPerson(String type){
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("ENTREPRENEUR")){
            return new Entre();
        }
        else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")){
            return new Empl();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can write type specific factory method in  `PersonFactory` class. like PersonFactory.createEmployee and PersonFactory.createEntrepreneur

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you're trying to access properties of `Emlp` or `Entre` you MUST cast the object to that type. Otherwise, all the compiler knows is that these are `Person` objects. It's the very purpose of inheritance and abstraction.

Comment: So the only solution is to separete the factory methods so that each one returns its own specific type? There's no way i can fit it in one factory method?
At what point should i cast? i tried "Empl e = factory.getPerson("Employee")" also tried "Empl e = (Empl)factory.getPerson("Employee")" and none of these return an Employee object since the getPerson Method returns a "Person" object.